# Type error: ...cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file

Tags: typescript, next.js, cypress

I am attempting to *run build* my NextJS app. I'm using Cypress for testing and trying out Typescript.
I am getting a:

```
Type error: 'home.cy.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
```

location: ./cypress/e2e/home.cy.ts:1:1

github: https://github.com/GSdaBlessedFist/unsplash-inspired/blob/main/cypress/e2e/home.cy.ts

- I do have an export in my index.ts file
- I tried setting `"isolatedModules": false`, in the tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting all cypress files from your tsconfig.json and then running the separate `npx tsc -p cypress/tsconfig.json --noEmit` process to check the types of your cypress files.

Some links that may be useful:

- [Cannot be compiled under 'isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-cannot-be-compiled-under-isolatedmodules#:%7E:text=The%20error%20%22Cannot%20be%20compiled%20under%20%27--isolatedModules%27%20because,the%20file%20to%20make%20it%20an%20ES%20module.)
- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/23062